# Read parameters in python from non .py file

Tags: python

I have a file with some parameters that are meant to be read by a Fortran code.
I would like to read the same file and have the same variable assignment in python.
How can I do it?

The .f90 file is as follows

```
Nsc = 9

dLK = 0.0050 ! = (\nu^3/\epsilon)^(1/4). dLK_Simu256 = 5e-3
rmin = 50.0
dnorm = dLK / rmin


dir_sc  = "sc_data/aaVATtest20Jan/"
dir_in  = "512_no_B0/"
dir_out = "512_no_B0/out/"

datestr = "1790037599" 
! 1790037599
! 1790231999
! 1790512799
! 1790836799
! 1791088799


theta_s = 80.0   !angle w/ the z axis. 0 is along z, 90 is in the xy plane
phi_s   = 5.0    !angle w/ the x axis
```

Comment: That seems like an overcomplication. A much better solution is to have the parameters in a single text file and have both Python and Fortran read this file.

Comment: ^ a much better idea if you  are keeping those in .f90 file just for the sake of configuration

Comment: http://www.numericalexpert.com/blog/fotran90_to_python/f90_to_py.html

Comment: @tripleee I will probably end up using your suggestion. Many thanks!